# How do i run rake db:* on test and development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey so I am running alot of rake db: commands on my test and development environment while bootstrapping my app.

Is there any way to run a rake db:rollback on both test and development at the same time?  All would be fine as well.

Comment: Sorry for ridiculous answer, didn't read all question. Maybe you could make alias in your terminal client (bash or zsh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Rails 4.1, any structural changes you make to your development db will automatically be propagated to your test db. The `db:test:prepare` task has even been removed from Rails.

Before Rails 4.1, the simplest is probably to just chain `db:test:prepare` onto every `rake db` command you run. eg. `rake db:migrate db:test:prepare`

Comment: Also, just found rake db:reset which drops the database first.  Thanks